How to freelook in 3d in godot using only touchpad and keyboard as I am using laptop
I am trying to  make a project in godot. I want to freelook in 3d in a godot project like a first person perspective but do not know any key combinations to do so as I am using laptop and do not have mouse.

take a look at this tutorial

You should check out the tutorial @M. R. M has provided.
If you only have a touchpad, you maybe need to emulate 3 button mouse. Go to Editor -> Editor Settings -> General -> Editors -> 3D -> Navigation -> Emulate 3 Button Mouse and check the tickbox.
Now use Alt with touchpad to rotate, Shift with touchpad to pan.


I have done this but i can now rotate from the center only... i want to look from every angle and not only from the center just like a first person game... so that i can look objects placed far away from the center as well. i do not know how to do it with touchpad. please help

Sorry but I didn't get your problem at first. Does your touchpad have right button? Just hold the right button and ues touchpad for free look.
